# magento payment/order flow

Tags: orders

I'm implementing magento plugin and I need place order programatically.
After payment is authorize (i use `sales_order_save_commit_after` event) i create invoice and shipping(programatically). After that order is set to processing.
Now I want to confirm order and request confirmation to payment gateway.
I assume that magento should do this automatically. But I dont know when. 
When (and where) confirmation to payment gateway is triggered? Where can I find detailed information about this process?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use `sales_order_invoice_pay` because all payment methods use `$order->pay()`,,in this event you can check total paid amount and all other things.

Also, it is very difficult to explain the payment flow in one answer, but I would suggest just going through the below links, may be you will get some better understanding.

[Link 1](http://www.ecomdev.org/2012/08/28/magento-checkout-functionality-concept.html)

[Link 2](https://www.gliffy.com/publish/1774620/)

[Link 3](http://www.mexbs.com/magento-order-statestatus-flow/)

Comment: Sorry Keyur, answers was very helpful but this is not direct answer for main question. When and  where confirmation request is triggered? I made few things like create shipment, create invoice and one of these things trigger confirmation request to payment gateway and change overall status of order to completed